# ASP MVC PartialView is returned without layout (Razor)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, partial-views

The title says it all so here's some code:

Partial in question is called with button click:

```
<div class="red">@ViewData["komunikat"]</div><br />
<p>
     @if (serwisUser.isAdmin || serwisUser.isUtrzymanie)
     {
        <input type="submit" name="btnUtrzymania" id="WybierzUtrzymania" value="Wprowadź nowe warunki dla zaznaczonych utrzymań" />
        <input id="txtIlosc" type="text" style="width: 20px; " value="1"/>
        <input type="button" name="btnUtrzymania" onclick="javascript:dodajAplikacje();" id="DodajAplikacje" value="Dodaj aplikację do utrzymań" />
            }
</p>
```

dodajAplikacje() function:

```
function dodajAplikacje()
{
    var klientID = '@ViewData["klientID"].ToString()';
    var ilosc = $("#txtIlosc").val();

    if (klientID != "")
    {
        $('#listaAplikacji').load('/Utrzymania/_DodajAplikacjeDoUtrzymania/' + klientID + '/' + ilosc);
    }
    else
    {
        ("Proszę wybrać klienta");
    }
}
```

This loads partial view with editable form, after saving changes which do not pass validation, partial view is returned with user's input. So nothing fancy. Problem is that if validation fails partial view is returned without parent view and layout, just white page with simple table.

Partial view:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("_DodajAplikacjeDoUtrzymania", "Utrzymania", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "listaAplikacji", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace }))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Dodaj aplikację do utrzymań</legend>
<div id="ListaUtrzyman" class="t-widget t-grid">        
            <table id="utrzymania" cellspacing="0">
            <thead class="t-grid-header">
                <tr>
                    <th rowspan="2"  class="t-header">
                        Nazwa Aplikacji
                    </th>
                    <th colspan="2"  class="t-header_rowspan">
                        Okres obowiązywania nowej umowy
                    </th>
                    <th colspan="3"  class="t-header_rowspan">
                        Czas realizacji SLA [w dniach]
                    </th>
                    <th rowspan="2"  class="t-header">
                        Komentarz do umowy
                    </th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th class="t-header_rowspan2">
                        Rozpoczęcie
                    </th>
                    <th class="t-header_rowspan2_last">
                        Wygaśnięcie
                    </th>
                    <th class="t-header_rowspan2">
                        Krytyczne
                    </th>
                    <th class="t-header_rowspan2">
                        Zwykłe
                    </th>
                    <th class="t-header_rowspan2_last">
                        Zadania
                    </th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                    @{int i = 0;
                    }
                    @foreach (var item in Model)
                    {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                           @Html.DropDownList("[" + i + "].aplikacjaID", (List<SelectListItem>)ViewData["listaAplikacji"])

                           @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m[i].aplikacjaID)


                           @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].klientID)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.Telerik().DatePickerFor(m => m[i].dataWprowadzenia).ShowButton(true).Format("yyyy-MM-dd").Name("[" + i + "].dataWprowadzenia").HtmlAttributes(new { @id = i + "-dataWprowadzenia" }).Value(DateTime.Now)

                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m[i].dataWprowadzenia)
                            @if (i == 0 && Model.Count > 1)
                            { <input type="image" onclick="PowielKrytyczne('dataWprowadzenia'); return false;" alt="Powiel" src="../../Content/images/down arrow.png" style="width: 16px; float: right;" /> }
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.Telerik().DatePickerFor(m => m[i].dataWygasniecia).ShowButton(true).Format("yyyy-MM-dd").Name("[" + i + "].dataWygasniecia").HtmlAttributes(new { @id = i + "-dataWygasniecia" }).Value(DateTime.Now.AddYears(1))
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m[i].dataWygasniecia)
                            @if (i == 0 && Model.Count > 1)
                            { <input type="image" onclick="PowielKrytyczne('dataWygasniecia'); return false;" alt="Powiel" src="../../Content/images/down arrow.png" style="width: 16px; float: right;" /> }
                        </td>
@*                        <td>
                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m[i].czySLA, new { @id = i + "-czySLA" })
                            @if (i == 0 && Model.Count > 1)
                            { <input type="image" onclick="PowielCheckBox('czySLA'); return false;" alt="Powiel" src="../../Content/images/down arrow.png" style="width: 16px; float: right;" /> }
                        </td>*@
                        <td>
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].czasKrytyczny, new { @style = "width:50px", @id = i + "-czasKrytyczny", @class = "number" })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m[i].czasKrytyczny)
                            @if (i == 0 && Model.Count > 1)
                            { <input type="image" onclick="PowielKrytyczne('czasKrytyczny'); return false;" alt="Powiel" src="../../Content/images/down arrow.png" style="width: 16px; float: right;" /> }
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].czasNormalny, new { @style = "width:50px", @id = i + "-czasNormalny", @class = "number" })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m[i].czasNormalny)
                            @if (i == 0 && Model.Count > 1)
                            { <input type="image" onclick="PowielKrytyczne('czasNormalny'); return false;" alt="Powiel" src="../../Content/images/down arrow.png" style="width: 16px; float: right;" /> }
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].czasZadanie, new { @style = "width:50px", @id = i + "-czasZadanie", @class = "number" })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m[i].czasZadanie)
                            @if (i == 0 && Model.Count > 1)
                            { <input type="image" onclick="PowielKrytyczne('czasZadanie'); return false;" alt="Powiel" src="../../Content/images/down arrow.png" style="width: 16px; float: right;" /> }
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m[i].komentarz, new { @id = i + "-komentarz" })
                            @if (i == 0 && Model.Count > 1)
                            { <input type="image" onclick="PowielKrytyczne('komentarz'); return false;" alt="Powiel" src="../../Content/images/down arrow.png" style="width: 16px; float: right;" /> }
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                            i++;
                    }

            </table>
            </div>
            <p>
                <input type="submit" id="ZapiszZmiany" value="Zapisz" disabled="disabled"/>
                <input type="button" id="PowrotDoListy" value="Powrót do listy utrzymań" />
            </p>  


    </fieldset>
}
```

Post method:

```
    [Authorize]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult _DodajAplikacjeDoUtrzymania(List<aplikacja_UtrzymanieAdd> utrzymanie)
    {
        serwisLoggedUser serwisUser = (serwisLoggedUser)Session["serwisUser"];
        if (serwisUser.isAdmin || serwisUser.isUtrzymanie)
        {
            ViewData["DodajUtrzymanie"] = @"class = selected";
            ViewData["czyWyswietlac"] = @"style = display:none;";

            string listaNowychAplikacji = string.Empty;

            Guid klientId;

            if(Session["klientId"] != null || Session["klientIdListaUtrzyman"] != null)
                klientId = (Guid)(Session["klientId"] ?? Session["klientIdListaUtrzyman"]);
            else
                return PartialView("_404");

            ViewData["listaAplikacji"] = listaAplikacji(klientId);

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                using (serwisCurrendaEntities entites = new serwisCurrendaEntities())
                {
                    foreach (aplikacja_UtrzymanieAdd utrz in utrzymanie)
                    {
                        serwis_Utrzymanie noweUtrzymanie = new serwis_Utrzymanie();
                        noweUtrzymanie.aplikacjaID = utrz.aplikacjaID;
                        noweUtrzymanie.czasKrytyczny = utrz.czasKrytyczny;
                        noweUtrzymanie.czasNormalny = utrz.czasNormalny;
                        noweUtrzymanie.czasZadanie = utrz.czasZadanie;
                        noweUtrzymanie.czySLA = utrz.czySLA;
                        noweUtrzymanie.czyUs = false;
                        if (utrz.dataWprowadzenia == null)
                        {
                            noweUtrzymanie.dataWprowadzenia = utrz.dataKoncaUtrzymania.Value;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            noweUtrzymanie.dataWprowadzenia = utrz.dataWprowadzenia.Value;
                        }
                        noweUtrzymanie.dataWygasniecia = utrz.dataWygasniecia;
                        noweUtrzymanie.klientID = klientId;
                        noweUtrzymanie.komentarz = utrz.komentarz;
                        entites.AddToserwis_Utrzymanie(noweUtrzymanie);
                        listaNowychAplikacji += noweUtrzymanie.serwis_Aplikacje.nazwaAplikacji + ", ";

                        TempData["klient"] = entites.serwis_Klienci.Where(k => k.klientID == klientId).FirstOrDefault().nazwa;
                        TempData["klientID"] = klientId;

                        Logger.Instance.AddLog("serwisCurrendaAdministrator.Controllers.UtrzymaniaController._DodajAplikacjeDoUtrzymania", Level.Info, String.Format("Użytkownik domenowy {0} dla klienta {1} dodał nowe utrzymanie dla {2}: rozpoczęcie {3}, wygaśnięcie {4}.", User.Identity.Name, TempData["klient"], noweUtrzymanie.serwis_Aplikacje.nazwaAplikacji, noweUtrzymanie.dataWprowadzenia, noweUtrzymanie.dataWygasniecia));
                    }

                    entites.SaveChanges();

                    TempData["Message"] = "Dodano utrzymania!";

                    return RedirectToAction("ListaUtrzyman", new { klientID = klientId });
                }
            }

            return View("_DodajAplikacjeDoUtrzymania", utrzymanie);
        }

        return PartialView("_403");
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

return PartialView will not return view with layout. return view will render the layout and make sure layout is not set to null in your _viewstart.cshtml.

Answer (score 0):

Return PartialView if ModelState is not Valid

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
  ....
}
return PartialView("_DodajAplikacjeDoUtrzymania", utrzymanie);
```

**DodajAplikacjeDoUtrzymania** View:

```
@model List<aplikacja_UtrzymanieAdd>    
@{
  layout = null;
}
```